# sh fun.sh : No such file or directory gcc: fatal error: no input files

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, gcc

I am creating a shell file on the fly containing following commands

```
 #!/bin/sh
    gcc -Wall -c *.c
    gcc -shared -o libr.so *.o
```

When I cd to that  location and run the shell script using this command `sh fun.sh`, I am getting following error

```
sh fun.sh : No such file or directory 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Typing these commands one by one in the linux does the work but shell script is not working. Kindly help me out with this

Comment: Does `fun.sh` have DOS-style (CRLF) endings? Check with `file fun.sh`

Comment: Are there any `.c` files in that directory?

Comment: Hi Bib Yes there are two .c files

Comment: Could you please make sure that the full error message is correctly represented in the question. The error message is formatted strangely, with spaces around `:` and with the full command at the start. It looks like the shell is saying it can't find `gcc`, but then `gcc` is saying that it didn't get any input files (formatted in a way that only makes sense if `nullglob` was set in the `bash` shell, which, AFAICS, it is not).

Comment: @PRIYANSHUMISHRA are you actually running the script from the directory with the .c files in it, or does the script just lie in the same directory?

Comment: this really doesn't look like the verbatim copy and pasted error message including line breaks. With the incomplete information given, it's very hard to help you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes both are in the same directory

Comment: it something has to be done with the formatting in unix. When I am doing dos2unix, it does the work. Should I add anything in the script?

Comment: @steeldriver file fun.sh is showing something like this fun.sh: cannot open `fun.sh' (Stale file handle)

Comment: @PRIYANSHUMISHRA "_something like this_" is useless. As already asked, please [provide the complete and exact error message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/713197/edit), with formatting to ensure newlines are in the right place, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I know the mistake I was making. I was creating this shell script on the fly. I created a template script.sh and created a MATLAB function to automate the process so that content of the shell script gets added dynamically. The mistake I was doing, I created the template script in Windows, and uploaded it on the network. The template script was written in Windows, though I was generating this shell script on the Linux.
When I did dos2inux, it worked.
Now when I am writing template file in Linux, and generating the script, it is working fine.
Thanks everyone for you answers.